# Root Finding using Secant method

Tags: roots, matlab, secant

I am currently trying to write a matlab code that will use the secant method to find a root of a function f(x) while only using the initial guess Xr = 1.0 and Del = 10^-6. I have solved the problem analytically and got a final root after a few iterations but I do not know how to translate that into Matlab while keeping the output in a table that displays the number of iterations, root estimate (Xi), func value @ root estimate (f(Xi)) and the approx error that comes with this method. I would appreciate any help that will guide me to a final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you're given a function secStep that runs a secant iteration step for your particular problem with the function f. Suppose you're going to do nSteps iterations and your initial guess is x0. Then you can do the following:

```
table=zeros(nSteps+1,3);
table(1,1)=0;
table(1,2)=x0;
table(1,3)=f(x0);
for k=2:(nSteps+1)
    table(k,1)=k-1;
    xk=secStep(table(k-1,2));
    table(k,2)=xk;
    table(k,3)=f(xk);
end
```

This doesn't include an error estimate in the table; how exactly you would do that depends on your exact problem. There isn't a universal way to do it, unlike with, say, bisection.

You can modify this slightly to use a while loop if you are not performing a preset number of iterations.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Ian. I am very new to matlab so although do not understand the secStep part of this, I will research and try to see if I can.

Comment: That part is just saying: to get table(k,2), perform a secant iteration step on table (k-1,2). You do not necessarily need to make that into a function like I suggested.

Comment: okay I need to get the secant method part in matlab correct yet so lets say my func was something like 10x^2 - 6x - 8. How would I code that using my Xr and Del till it converges? I can get the table part correct afterwards.

Comment: Is your tolerance for a backward error, i.e. $|x-x^*|$, or a forward error, i.e. $|f(x)|$? The latter is how we most commonly do things, because the former is usually impossible to compute (if we could compute it then we could analytically solve the problem) and frequently difficult to estimate. But if you have an analytical solution already then you can do the former.

Comment: The error approx that i am using is a forward error as you said.                  | Xr^i - Xr^i-1| / Xr^i

Comment: That is a relative estimated backward error; in practice this is dangerous but it is also commonly used. Anyway it is routine to make the loop be a while loop with that as your stopping criterion.

Comment: Could you help me set up a basis for it and see if I can make it from there? This is the second time I have ever had to use matlab for homework so its still pretty confusing to me.

Comment: Try to write up an appropriate while loop for me to critique. (I don't want to do your entire assignment.)

Comment: Okay give me some time to get back into it. Will update in a bit.

Comment: Note that the way that I suggested will not quite work because I forgot that the secant method requires *two* points. But something very similar works.